# Почему записи в таблице БД расположены не по порядку?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, php, sql

Заношу в базу данных записи. А они почему-то не по порядку записываются.
И выводятся из базы не по порядку. Я сделал сортировку по ID для правильного
вывода, но всё-таки интересно.

Структура таблицы
[image: Структура таблицы]

Записи в таблице
[image: записи в таблице].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно теории реляционных БД в таблицах отсутствует порядок по умолчанию. Порядок задается сортировкой при выводе (запросе) к таблице. Если сортировка не задана, то порядок вывода определяется первичным ключом.

Comment: >>  Если сортировка не задана, то порядок вывода определяется первичным ключом.

Если сортировка не задана, то порядок вывода на усмотрение СУБД. Да, иногда он может совпасть с первичным ключем.

Comment: @KoVadim - согласен